# Assign python Decimal objects to MySQL DECIMAL columns

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, decimal

I have a table "City" defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE `City` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `lat` decimal(9,6) default NULL,
  `long` decimal(9,6) default NULL,
  `lm_index` int(11) default NULL,
  `num_business` int(11) default NULL,
  `postal_code` varchar(16) default NULL,
PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

I use python with SQLAlchemy to map this table:

```
Base = declarative_base(engine)

class City(Base):
    ''''''
    __tablename__ = 'City'
    __table_args__ = {'autoload':True}
    def __init__(self, id, lat, long, lm_index, numbiz, postal):
        self.id = id
        self.lat = lat
        self.long = long
        self.lm_index = lm_index
        self.num_business = numbiz
        self.postal_code = postal
```

If I understand the python decimal package correctly, this should work:

```
from decimal import *

getcontext().prec = 6
lat = 12.11111111
long = 46.2222222

city = City(1, Decimal(str(lat)), Decimal(str(long)), 0, 0, 0)
```

However, I still get the same errors as I do when I don't call Decimal():

```
Warning: Data truncated for column 'lat' at row 1
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Just curious, why are you overriding `__init__()` instead of using `sqlalchemy.types.DECIMAL`? That way `sqlalchemy` handles everything.

Comment: I'm a SQLAlchemy newbie and all the examples I've ever seen override __init__.  I've searched docs but can't figure out how to do it the way you suggest.  If you could give me a tip I'd be grateful.

Comment: Did you visit the official documentation? Because the very first example on this page shows what I'm saying http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/extensions/declarative.html

Answer (score 4):

My guess is, because you're sending an instance of `Decimal`, the `lat` or `long` fields are being turned to something like a string representation of the instance. Again, I'm not sure. You can use `pdb` to debug that.

Anyway, there are better ways to deal with `DECIMAL` fields in `MySQL` via SQLAlchemy. Instead of handling the decimal processing yourself, you could just let sqlalchemy take care of it -

from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
Base = declarative_base()

```
class City(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'City'
    __table_args__ = {'autoload':True}

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    lat =  Column(Numeric(precision=9, scale=6))
    long =  Column(Numeric(precision=9, scale=6))
    ...
```

`Numeric` field returns `decimal.Decimal` objects by default, applying conversion as needed.

Then you can initiate it as -

```
city = City(lat=12.11111111, long=46.2222222, ...)
```

If you override `__init__()` then you can initiate it like `City(12.1111, 46.2222)`, but I prefer keeping the column name, that way you know at a glance which field is getting what, instead of counting the number of values each time.

I haven't tested the code, but it should work. Try.

Comment: I had tried declaring the Column explicitly as Numeric(9,6) earlier, then calling `city = City(id=123, lat=12.11111111, long=46.22222222)`

Same warning message.